# Get sub collection in List<class> form

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have a LINQ to EF query that returns data in a class form. The class has a `List<RecipeCategories>` property that I need to populate. The RecipeCategories table is a relationship table between the Recipe table and the RecipeCategories table, and can be many to many. I found enough information to get the code to compile, but it errors at runtime and I haven't been able to figure out how to get this right.

```
ri = (from r in recipeData.Recipes
              where r.ID == recipeId
              select new RecipeItem
              {
                  Id = r.ID,
                  ProductId = r.Product.ID,
                  RecipeName = r.recipeName,
                  RecipeDescription = r.recipeDescription,
                  Servings = r.servings.HasValue ? r.servings.Value : 0,
                  CreatedDate = r.createdDate,
                  PrepTime = r.prepTime.HasValue ? r.servings.Value : 0,
                  CookTime = r.cookTime.HasValue ? r.servings.Value : 0,
                  Approved = r.approved,
                  RecipeInstructions = r.recipeInstructions,
                  RecipeIngredients = r.recipeIngredients,
                  RecipeCategories = r.RecipeCategories.Select(i => new RecipeCategoryItem { Id = i.ID, CategoryName = i.categoryName }).ToList()
              }).First();
```

This is the error I get.

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RecipeCategoryItem] ToList[RecipeCategoryItem](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[RecipeCategoryItem])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

The part that I am working on is this line.

```
RecipeCategories = r.RecipeCategories.Select(i => new RecipeCategoryItem { Id = i.ID, CategoryName = i.categoryName }).ToList()
```

RecipeCategories is a `List<RecipeCategoryItem>` property.

Is what I am trying to do possible, and if so, how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're calling ToList inside of what gets turned into a larger query. Remove the call to .ToList().

The problem is that everything in your query gets turned into a big expression tree, which Entity Framework tries to translate into a SQL statement. "ToList" has no meaning from a SQL standpoint, so you shouldn't call it anywhere *inside* your query.

In most cases, you want to call ToList on your overall query before returning it, to ensure that the query is evaluated and the results are loaded into memory. In this case, you're only returning one object, so the call to `First` does essentially the same thing.

How important is it that RecipeCategories be a `List<RecipeCategoryItem>`? If you could make it IEnumerable instead, then you can remove the call to `ToList` without any problem.

If it's absolutely necessary that you have a `List`, then you will first need to pull all the information in using an initial Entity Framework query and anonymous types (without calling ToList), and then convert the data you receive into the object type you want before returning it.

Or you could build your RecipeInfo object piecemeal from multiple queries, like so:

```
var ri = (from r in recipeData.Recipes
            where r.ID == recipeId
            select new RecipeItem
            {
                Id = r.ID,
                ProductId = r.Product.ID,
                RecipeName = r.recipeName,
                RecipeDescription = r.recipeDescription,
                Servings = r.servings.HasValue ? r.servings.Value : 0,
                CreatedDate = r.createdDate,
                PrepTime = r.prepTime.HasValue ? r.servings.Value : 0,
                CookTime = r.cookTime.HasValue ? r.servings.Value : 0,
                Approved = r.approved,
                RecipeInstructions = r.recipeInstructions,
                RecipeIngredients = r.recipeIngredients,
            }).First();
var rc = from c in recipeData.RecipeCategories
         where c.Recipes.Any(r => r.ID == recipeId)
         select new RecipeCategoryItem 
         {
            Id = c.ID, CategoryName = c.categoryName
         };
ri.RecipeCategories = ri.ToList();
```

Note that this last example will cause two database trips, but will cause less data to be sent across the wire.

Comment: I had tried your second way before, but c.Recipe doesn't expose any fields, and I think it is because the relationship table doesn't actually show up in the data model because it is a link table between recipes and recipecategories. I tried the first way you said, but I am not sure how to structure the linq query now. This is what I have. [CODE]RecipeCategories = r.RecipeCategories.Select(i => new RecipeCategoryItem { Id = i.ID, CategoryName = i.categoryName })[/CODE]

Comment: Last comment timed out. I get this error. Can't convert IEnumerable<RecipeCategoryItem> to RecipeCategoryItems

Comment: @Ben: It sounds like Recipes and RecipeCategories have a many-to-many relationship, then? I edited my answer accordingly. Let me know how that works out for you.  With the first way I said, you'll need to use an anonymous type by changing `select new RecipeItem {` to `select new {`. Then your second step would be to take this anonymous object and create a new RecipeItem based on its data.

Comment: Yes, Recipes and RecipeCategories has a many-to-many relationship. I couldnt' quite get the IEnumerator way to work, but your second suggestion worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have a solution to the problem. Use dynamic type.

```
public class BoxImageViewDetailDto
{
    public Guid PropertyId { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string SubTitle { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string SubDescription { get; set; }

    public decimal? PropertyValue { get; set; }
    public byte? UnitsFloor { get; set; }

    public dynamic ImagensRowsVar { get; set; }
    public List<ImageViewDto> ImagensRows 
    {
        get
        {
            return (List<ImageViewDto>)this.ImagensRowsVar; 
        }
    }

    public int ImagensRowsTotal { get; set; }
}

CorretorDaVez.DTO.UserControls.BoxImageViewDetailDto c = (from p in entities.rlt_Property
  join pc in entities.rlt_PropertyPicture on p.PropertyId equals pc.PropertyId
  where p.PropertyId == propertyId
  orderby p.CreateDate descending
  select new CorretorDaVez.DTO.UserControls.BoxImageViewDetailDto
  {
      PropertyId = p.PropertyId,
      Title = p.Title,
      PropertyValue = p.PropertyValue,
      Description = p.Description,
      UnitsFloor = p.UnitsFloor,
      ImagensRowsTotal = p.rlt_PropertyPicture.Count,
      ImagensRowsVar = p.rlt_PropertyPicture.Select(s => new CorretorDaVez.DTO.UserControls.ImageViewDto { PropertyId = p.PropertyId, ImagePath = pc.PhotoUrl})
  }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
    var ri = (from r in recipeData.Recipes
              where r.ID == recipeId
              select new RecipeItem
              {
                  Id = r.ID,
                  ProductId = r.Product.ID,
                  RecipeName = r.recipeName,
                  RecipeDescription = r.recipeDescription,
                  Servings = r.servings.HasValue ? r.servings.Value : 0,
                  CreatedDate = r.createdDate,
                  PrepTime = r.prepTime.HasValue ? r.servings.Value : 0,
                  CookTime = r.cookTime.HasValue ? r.servings.Value : 0,
                  Approved = r.approved,
                  RecipeInstructions = r.recipeInstructions,
                  RecipeIngredients = r.recipeIngredients,
                  RecipeCategories = from rc in recipeData.RecipeCategories
                                     where rc.Recipes.Any(r => r.ID == recipeId)
                                     select new RecipeCategoryItem{
                                              Id = rc.ID, 
                                              CategoryName = rc.categoryName
                                           } 
      ).First();
```