# How can I use LINQ to populate a collection inside a collection?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ code that I created:

```
 QuestionDetail questions = _questionsRepository
                .GetAll()
                .Include(q => q.Answers)
                .Select(m => new QuestionDetail
                {
                    QuestionId = m.QuestionId,
                    Text = m.Text,
                    Answers // << I am not sure how to populate this
                            // << I need to have a new collection 
                            // << created from a subset of the m.Answers
                })
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

My problem is that I am not sure how to populate the `ICollection<AnswerDetail> Answers` collection that is part of the QuestionDetail. What I need is to somehow select from the m.Answers and use this to populate the AnswerDetail collection. I know I cannot use new AnswerDetail as Answers is a collection.

Can anyone help and tell me how I could do this.

Below I have listed some of the classes for this. To make it simpler I removed some fields from the Question and Answer classes.

```
public class QuestionDetail
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AnswerDetail> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class AnswerDetail
{
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Correct { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Response { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public Question()
    {
        this.Answers = new List<Answer>();
    }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why collection properties are virtual and others are not? (just curious)

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286359/how-can-i-include-down-more-than-one-level-in-linq?rq=1

Comment: @Pieter - It's not a duplicate. The classes are similar but what I am trying to do is the next thing on in the development cycle.

Comment: @Sarge - thanks for pointing this out. I think the ICollection<AnswerDetail> Answers should not be virtual. I will change this.

Answer (score 2):

For what I can see this should work:

```
Answers = m.Answers.Select(a => 
              new AnswerDetail { AnswerId = a.AnswerId, 
                                 Text = a.Text }).ToList(),
```

You have a list of `Answer` and transform them to a list of `AnswerDetail`.

Comment: Unfortunately this gives the following error message: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 
'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Models.Http.AnswerDetail] 
ToList[AnswerDetail](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Models.Http.AnswerDetail])'
method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: When I skip the ToList() I get a different error message: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Models.Http.AnswerDetail>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Models.Http.AnswerDetail>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730179/get-sub-collection-in-listclass-form) seems the same issue, maybe can help.

Answer (score 1):

if you need a subset of `q.Answers` and you have a condition you can do:

```
QuestionDetail questions = _questionsRepository
            .GetAll()
            .Include(q => q.Answers)
            .Select(m => new QuestionDetail
            {
                QuestionId = m.QuestionId,
                Text = m.Text,
                Answers = m.Answers.Where(x=>yourCondition)
            })
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Take(1) instead of FirstOrDefault project result on the "outside":

```
QuestionDetail questions = _questionsRepository
        .GetAll()
        .Include(q => q.Answers)
        .Take(1)
        .ToList()
        .Select(m => new QuestionDetail
        {
            QuestionId = m.QuestionId,
            Text = m.Text,
            Answers = m.Answers.Select(a => 
                              new AnswerDetail { AnswerId = a.AnswerId, 
                                                 Text = a.Text }).ToList()
        });
```